# Is it possible Async Await - Fluent builder approach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This my road of growing up: callbacks, promises, async/await. I keep in mind a pattern - fluent builder that looks more to interpreter. I would like to mix async/await with interpreter. Is it possible? I feel that it is not possible. But I can define why exactly.
I have:

```
  after(async () => {
    await shellContainer.uninstall()
    await shellContainer.dispose()
  })
```

I am interesting in:

```
after(async () => {
    await shellContainer
      .uninstall()
      .dispose()
  })
```

Regards.

Comment: Can you alter the code of `shellContainer`'s methods?

Comment: Yes, I can. I am a developer of the container. I can change the architecture.

Comment: There is the second await. So it returns  a promise exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To separate concerns, you could introduce a dedicated [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) which implements the fluent interface.

With that you only need to return a promise from the final `build` method, making things a lot simpler.

The following is a rather crude but functional example:

```js
class ShellContainer
{
  uninstall() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('uninstalled');
        resolve();
      }, 400 + Math.random() * 600);
    });
  }

  dispose() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('disposed');
        resolve();
      }, 400 + Math.random() * 600);
    });
  }
}

class ShellContainerBuilder
{
  container;
  plan;

  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.container = new ShellContainer();
    this.plan = () => Promise.resolve();
  }

  stage(op) {
    this.plan = ((prev) => () => prev().then(op))(this.plan);
  }

  uninstall() {
    this.stage(() => this.container.uninstall());
    return this;
  }

  dispose() {
    this.stage(() => this.container.dispose());
    return this;
  }

  build() {
    return this.plan().then(() => this.container);
  }
}

(async () => {
  console.log('starting w/o builder:');
  const shellContainer1 = new ShellContainer();
  await shellContainer1.uninstall();
  await shellContainer1.dispose();
  console.log('w/o builder done.');

  console.log('starting w/ builder:');
  const shellContainer2 = await (new ShellContainerBuilder()).uninstall().dispose().build();
  console.log(shellContainer2);
  console.log('w/ builder done.');
})();
```

Comment: I really like your solution. But It demands extra architecture staff. Also extra commands appear these are needed to control the queue of promises. I will use the approach when I really need the builder functionality. Right now I need syntax sugar for chaining. You've proved that the price is not low.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `.uninstall` to return the instance (`shellContainer`) while assigning its Promise to a property of the instance, and retrieving that Promise in the chained call, yes, it's possible:

```
class ShellContainer {
  uninstall() {
    // Chain or construct a Promise and assign the result to a property of the instance:
    this.uninstProm = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // do stuff
    });
    return this;
  }
  dispose() {
    return this.uninstProm.then(() => {
      // do stuff
    });
  }
}
```

and then,

```
await shellContainer
  .uninstall()
  .dispose()
```

will resolve once `dispose` finishes.

Note that with this approach, calling `uninstall` *by itself* may result in unexpected behavior, since `.uninsall` will be returning the instance synchronously, rather than the Promise. You might consider an extra argument or something to indicate whether you want to chain the `uninstall` call with something else, or whether you want the Promise to be returned directly, perhaps something like

```
class ShellContainer {
  uninstall(doChain) {
    // Chain or construct a Promise and assign the result to a property of the instance:
    this.uninstProm = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // do stuff
    });
    return doChain ? this : this.uninstProm;
  }
  dispose() {
    return this.uninstProm.then(() => {
      // do stuff
    });
  }
}
```

and

```
  await shellContainer
    .uninstall(true)
    .dispose()
```

or just

```
await shellContainer.uninstall(); // no doChain argument
```

But if there's only going to be *one* Promise, there's not much need for `await` in many cases - it may not make the code clearer at all. For example

```
after(async () => {
  await shellContainer
    .uninstall()
    .dispose()
})
```

is equivalent to

```
after(() => shellContainer
              .uninstall()
              .dispose()
);
```

Comment: It wouldn't work since `.uninstall()` is an asynchronous function in your example. It will return a promise resolving to `this` and not `this` directly.

Comment: @certainperformance I've modified your snippet to disclose the problem https://jsfiddle.net/vlikin/oh4j17xr/10/

Comment: @viktor.likin You're returning a Promise from `uninstall`, when you should be returning `this` from `uninstall` (so that it can be chained with `dispose` properly), and access the created promise inside `dispose()`, as in the answer

Comment: @certainperformance Keep attention this is asynchronous, we always work with promises. Look at resolve(this). The console output shows the wrong order.

Comment: @viktor.likin Yes, I'm aware that this is asynchronous - but your returning of the Promise rather than assigning the Promise to a property of the instance is what's causing the problem. Just use the code in my answer instead, and it will work. You can't have `uninstall` unconditionally return a Promise, otherwise you won't be able to chain `.dispose()` onto the end of it.

Comment: @certainperformance Look the magic https://jsfiddle.net/vlikin/9uvmz68L/2/ it produces the right order. The reason why is below in the answer.

Comment: @certainperformance you say right things. But this proves that Interpreter with async can not coexist.

Comment: @certainperformance Please read the title of the question. What I really need.

Comment: @viktor.likin I'm not understanding why you can't assign to a property of the instance as the answer suggests - if you do that, it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/1mk5y8ad/

Answer (score 0):

The pattern - Interpreter that implements Fluent builder is not suitable for Async/Await. Because await is applied per an operation. There is not such syntax to process async in the middle of the chain. To handle async operations you should split chaining and wrap the operations by await operator like it is at the first code snippet.